# Red Hat OpenShift on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift

I just enabled openshift service on aws. How can I disable that? Will I be charged for enabling it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling the service only sets the permissions for you to be able to deploy ROSA clusters, you will only be charged if you explicitly create ROSA clusters.

Answer (score 5):

From a quick glance at the [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/rosa/pricing/) page I would say that costs occur only when an OpenShift cluster is provisioned.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Enablement is just giving the _ability_ to create clusters. Costs don't come in to play until an actual cluster is deployed.